# Javascript XPath emulator to replace XPathEvaluator

Tags: javascript, xpath, emulation

Has anyone tryed to replace the JS method XPathEvaluator ?

Is there any `emulator` or working code for all browsers, including IE ?

Even if slower, an emulator would be usefull.

i have this code : http://svn.coderepos.org/share/lang/javascript/javascript-xpath/trunk/release/javascript-xpath-latest.js

but when i fix it in one part, it cracks in other parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Wicked Good XPath](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2012/09/wicked-good-xpath-faster-javascript.html) - "a Google-authored pure JavaScript implementation of the DOM Level 3 XPath specification. We believe it to be the fastest XPath implementation available in JavaScript"?